# Parse a multiline email to var

Tags: c#, .net, regex, parsing

I'm attempting to parse a multi-line email so I can get at the data which is on its own newline under the heading in the body of the email.
It looks like this:

```
EMAIL STARTING IN APRIL

Marketing ID                                     Local Number
-------------------                              ----------------------
GR332230                                         0000232323

Dispatch Code                                    Logic code
-----------------                                -------------------
GX3472                                           1

Destination ID                                   Destination details
-----------------                                -------------------
3411144
```

It appears I am getting everything on each messagebox when I use string reader readline, though all I want is the data under each `------` as shown

This is my code:

```
foreach (MailItem mail in publicFolder.Items)
{
    if (mail != null)                  
    {

        if (mail is MailItem)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(mail.Body, "MailItem body");
            // Creates new StringReader instance from System.IO
            using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(mail.Body))
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) !=null) 
                //Loop over the lines in the string.
                if (mail.Body.Contains("Marketing ID"))
                {
                    // var localno = mail.Body.Substring(247,15);//not correct approach

                    // MessageBox.Show(localrefno);
                    //MessageBox.Show("found");
                    //var conexid = mail.Body.Replace(Environment.NewLine);

                    var regex = new Regex("<br/>", RegexOptions.Singleline);


                    MessageBox.Show(line.ToString());
                }
            }


            //var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            //foreach (var s in mail.Body.Split(' '))
            //{
            //    stringBuilder.Append(s).AppendLine();
            //}
            //MessageBox.Show(stringBuilder.ToString());



        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Nothing found for MailItem");
        }
    }
}
```

You can see I had numerous attempts with it, even using substring position and using regex. Please help me get the data from each line under the `---`.

Comment: I added a live demo to both my solutions, please check them out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a very good idea to do that with Regex because it is quite easy to forget the edge cases, not easy to understand, and not easy to debug. It's quite easy to get into a situation that the Regex hangs your CPU and times out. (I cannot make any comment to other answers yet. So, please check at least my other two cases before you pick your final solution.)

In your cases, the following Regex solution works for your provided example. However, some additional limitations are there: You need to make sure there are no empty values in the non-starting or non-ending column. Or, let's say if there are more than two columns and any one of them in the middle is empty will make the names and values of that line mismatched.

Unfortunately, I cannot give you a non-Regex solution because I don't know the spec, e.g.: Will there be empty spaces? Will there be TABs? Does each field has a fixed count of characters or will they be flexible? If it is flexible and can have empty values, what kind of rules to detected which columns are empty? I assume that it is quite possible that they are defined by the column name's length and will have only space as delimiter. If that's the case, there are two ways to solve it, two-pass Regex or write your own parser. If all the fields has fixed length, it would be even more easier to do: Just using the substring to cut the lines and then trim them.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public class Record{
        public string Name {get;set;}
        public string Value {get;set;}
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        var regex = new Regex(@"(?<name>((?!-)[\w]+[ ]?)*)(?>(?>[ \t]+)?(?<name>((?!-)[\w]+[ ]?)+)?)+(?:\r\n|\r|\n)(?>(?<splitters>(-+))(?>[ \t]+)?)+(?:\r\n|\r|\n)(?<value>((?!-)[\w]+[ ]?)*)(?>(?>[ \t]+)?(?<value>((?!-)[\w]+[ ]?)+)?)+", RegexOptions.Compiled);
        var testingValue =
@"EMAIL STARTING IN APRIL

Marketing ID                                     Local Number
-------------------                              ----------------------
GR332230                                         0000232323

Dispatch Code                                    Logic code
-----------------                                -------------------
GX3472                                           1

Destination ID                                   Destination details
-----------------                                -------------------
3411144";
        var matches = regex.Matches(testingValue);

        var rows = (
            from match in matches.OfType<Match>()
            let row = (
                from grp in match.Groups.OfType<Group>()
                select new {grp.Name, Captures = grp.Captures.OfType<Capture>().ToList()}
            ).ToDictionary(item=>item.Name, item=>item.Captures.OfType<Capture>().ToList())
            let names = row.ContainsKey("name")? row["name"] : null
            let splitters = row.ContainsKey("splitters")? row["splitters"] : null
            let values = row.ContainsKey("value")? row["value"] : null
            where names != null && splitters != null &&
                names.Count == splitters.Count &&
                (values==null || values.Count <= splitters.Count)
            select new {Names = names, Values = values}
            );

        var records = new List<Record>();
        foreach(var row in rows)
        {
            for(int i=0; i< row.Names.Count; i++)
            {
                records.Add(new Record{Name=row.Names[i].Value, Value=i < row.Values.Count ? row.Values[i].Value : ""});
            }
        }

        foreach(var record in records)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(record.Name + " = " + record.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

output:

```
Marketing ID  = GR332230 
Local Number = 0000232323
Dispatch Code  = GX3472 
Logic code = 1
Destination ID  = 3411144
Destination details =
```

Please note that this also works for this kind of message:
EMAIL STARTING IN APRIL

```
Marketing ID                                     Local Number
-------------------                              ----------------------
GR332230                                         0000232323

Dispatch Code                                    Logic code
-----------------                                -------------------
GX3472                                           1

Destination ID                                   Destination details
-----------------                                -------------------
                                                 3411144
```

output:

```
Marketing ID  = GR332230 
Local Number = 0000232323
Dispatch Code  = GX3472 
Logic code = 1
Destination ID  = 
Destination details = 3411144
```

Or this:

```
EMAIL STARTING IN APRIL

Marketing ID                                     Local Number
-------------------                              ----------------------


Dispatch Code                                    Logic code
-----------------                                -------------------
GX3472                                           1

Destination ID                                   Destination details
-----------------                                -------------------
                                                 3411144
```

output:

```
Marketing ID  = 
Local Number = 
Dispatch Code  = GX3472 
Logic code = 1
Destination ID  = 
Destination details = 3411144
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            try
            {
                var lines = email.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                int starts = 0, end = 0, length = 0;
                while (!lines[starts + 1].StartsWith("-")) starts++;
                for (int i = starts + 1; i < lines.Length; i += 3)
                {
                    var mc = Regex.Matches(lines[i], @"(?:^| )-");
                    foreach (Match m in mc)
                    {
                        int start = m.Value.StartsWith(" ") ? m.Index + 1 : m.Index;
                        end = start;
                        while (lines[i][end++] == '-' && end < lines[i].Length - 1) ;
                        length = Math.Min(end - start, lines[i - 1].Length - start);
                        string key = length > 0 ? lines[i - 1].Substring(start, length).Trim() : "";
                        end = start;
                        while (lines[i][end++] == '-' && end < lines[i].Length) ;
                        length = Math.Min(end - start, lines[i + 1].Length - start);
                        string value = length > 0 ? lines[i + 1].Substring(start, length).Trim() : "";
                        dict.Add(key, value);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Email is not in correct format");
            }
```

[Live Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/q9sihP)

Using Regular Expressions:

```
     var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        try
        {
            var lines = email.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            int starts = 0;
            while (!lines[starts + 1].StartsWith("-")) starts++;
            for (int i = starts + 1; i < lines.Length; i += 3)
            {
                var keys = Regex.Matches(lines[i - 1], @"(?:^| )(\w+\s?)+");
                var values = Regex.Matches(lines[i + 1], @"(?:^| )(\w+\s?)+");
                if (keys.Count == values.Count)
                    for (int j = 0; j < keys.Count; j++)

                        dict.Add(keys[j].Value.Trim(), values[j].Value.Trim());
                else // remove bug if value of first key in a line has no value
                {
                    if (lines[i + 1].StartsWith(" "))
                    {
                        dict.Add(keys[0].Value.Trim(), "");
                        dict.Add(keys[1].Value.Trim(), values[0].Value.Trim());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dict.Add(keys[0].Value, values[0].Value.Trim());
                        dict.Add(keys[1].Value.Trim(), "");
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Email is not in correct format");
        }
```

[Live Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kO0A1W)

Comment: Thanks for these demos, I can certainly work with this so I will accept your answer.

Comment: I tried to do some additions to the email format and its not breaking down the lines at the bottom. Kind of hard to explain, but I used your approach on my own .net fiddle here https://dotnetfiddle.net/6nMO2c#&togetherjs=yGdgSSGk3e

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt. I don't know if the email format can change (rows, columns, etc).

I can't think of an easy way to separate the columns besides checking for a double space (my solution).

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var emailBody = GetEmail();
        using (var reader = new StringReader(emailBody))
        {
            var lines = new List<string>();
            const int startingRow = 2; // Starting line to read from (start at Marketing ID line)
            const int sectionItems = 4; // Header row (ex. Marketing ID & Local Number Line) + Dash Row + Value Row + New Line

            // Add all lines to a list
            string line = "";
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                lines.Add(line.Trim()); // Add each line to the list and remove any leading or trailing spaces
            }

            for (var i = startingRow; i < lines.Count; i += sectionItems)
            {
                var currentLine = lines[i];
                var indexToBeginSeparatingColumns = currentLine.IndexOf("  "); // The first time we see double spaces, we will use as the column delimiter, not the best solution but should work

                var header1 = currentLine.Substring(0, indexToBeginSeparatingColumns);
                var header2 = currentLine.Substring(indexToBeginSeparatingColumns, currentLine.Length - indexToBeginSeparatingColumns).Trim();

                currentLine = lines[i+2]; //Skip dash line
                indexToBeginSeparatingColumns = currentLine.IndexOf("  ");

                string value1 = "", value2 = "";
                if (indexToBeginSeparatingColumns == -1) // Use case of there being no value in the 2nd column, could be better
                {
                    value1 = currentLine.Trim();
                }
                else
                {
                    value1 = currentLine.Substring(0, indexToBeginSeparatingColumns);
                    value2 = currentLine.Substring(indexToBeginSeparatingColumns, currentLine.Length - indexToBeginSeparatingColumns).Trim();
                }                    

                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3}", header1, value1, header2, value2));
            }
        }
    }

    static string GetEmail()
    {
        return @"EMAIL STARTING IN APRIL

                Marketing ID                                     Local Number
                -------------------                              ----------------------
                GR332230                                         0000232323

                Dispatch Code                                    Logic code
                -----------------                                -------------------
                GX3472                                           1

                Destination ID                                   Destination details
                -----------------                                -------------------
                3411144";
    }
}
```

Output looks something like this:

Marketing ID,GR332230,Local Number,0000232323
Dispatch Code,GX3472,Logic code,1
Destination ID,3411144,Destination details,

Answer (score 0):

Here is an aproach asuming you don't need the headers, info comes in order and mandatory.
This won't work for data that has spaces or optional fields.

```cs
foreach (MailItem mail in publicFolder.Items)
{
  MessageBox.Show(mail.Body, "MailItem body");
  // Split by line, remove dash lines.
  var data = Regex.Split(mail.Body, @"\r?\n|\r")
    .Where(l => !l.StartsWith('-'))
    .ToList();
  // Remove headers
  for(var i = data.Count -2; lines >= 0; i -2)
  {
    data.RemoveAt(i);
  }
  // now data contains only the info you want in the order it was presented.
  // Asuming info doesn't have spaces.
  var result = data.SelectMany(d => d.Split(' '));
  // WARNING: Missing info will not be present.
  // {"GR332230", "0000232323", "GX3472", "1", "3411144"}
}
```